# How long class attributes live in python (Django)

Tags: python-3.x, django, gunicorn

I have this class in my Django app:

```
 class MyClass:
   property_1 = []
 
   def add_elem(self):
     self.property_1.append(1)
     print(self.property_1)

MyClass().add_elem()
MyClass().add_elem()
```

The output will be:

- [1]
- [1, 1]

That means that when I start Django server, all the scripts(all app) are loaded to memory and as property_1 is a class attribute, every time I call add_elem(), I add a new '1' to the property? And property_1 will be cleaned only after restart server?

Comment: *will be cleaned only after restart server?* - Yes, it will be intialized again when you restart or reload your django server .

Comment: If you need to persist data throughout Django restarts I would suggest looking into Django's cache framework with something like Redis.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Thanks! That is what I was looking for! How do I check that question is answered and close it?